# How to consume BehaviorSubject in React app

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, behaviorsubject

My main application(not react) has BehaviorSubject data object. User clicks a button and he can open React side of the application in a child browser window.

The react side of the app has a component that takes data and creates tables with the data.

While being in the child window I can go to my debugger and do the following to see the subject values change in console.

```
window.opener.app.varCollection$.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(JSON.stringify(v))
});
```

How do i feed this data to a react component below? I am not sure how the subscription would work in React side.

```
<DataPanel jsonData={this.state.sysvarData} ></DataPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on the component itself, or on it's parent and pass the value to it as props.

Just subscribe to the observable on the **componentDidMount** event:

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.opener.app.varCollection$.subscribe(val => this.setState({value:val}))
}
```

A good practice is to handle the unsubscription on the **componentWillUnmount** event using the takeUntil operator and a Subject:

```
unmount$ = new Subject() //component class property

componentDidMount() {
   //if using rxjs 6:
   window.opener.app.varCollection$
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.unmount$)) 
     .subscribe(val => this.setState({value:val}))
   //if using rxjs 4 or 5:
   window.opener.app.varCollection$
     .takeUntil(this.unmount$)
     .subscribe(val => this.setState({value:val}))
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.unmount$.next(true)
}

render() {
   const {value} = this.state //now you have the value on the render funtion
   ...
}
```

Comment: subscribing in componentDidMount is not working for me. the state var is not getting updated.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the issue. It worked here, but only with the two files served from the same http server. Another solution is to use the postMessage on the parent, and  listen to the 'message' event on the child window.

Comment: i have the postMessage working as a backup. the subscribe and setting state worked when I put it in the Component Constructor. thanks for the ideas.